# Sending all info to ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i try to send all checkbox data to my ajax.What i want is that

[image]

If user click 2 or checkbox to send my ajax and ajax call a php code.
First of all,

In my view file: This is the code. Dont worry about {literal} its template_lite

```
  <a style="float: right" href='javascript:void(null);' onclick="deleteData2('PERSON_MOVIE',
                    {literal}{{/literal}
                        'MOVIE_ID':'{$movieId}','PERSON_ID':'{$mCast.id}','JOB_ID':'374'
                    {literal}}{/literal}
                );" ><input type=checkbox name="checkArtist[]"></a>
```

This my ajax

```
function deleteData2($table,$cols,$image)
{
     if (!$image) $image = false;
    $sendData = {
        'table':$table,
        'cols':$cols,
        'image':$image
    }

    $.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', $sendData, 
        function($data,$status){
            if($status=='success')
            {
                window.location.replace(window.location.pathname);
            }
        },'json');



}
```

How can i send array data to this ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Create the parameters as Object.

```
var objParams = new Object();
objParams.anarray = new Object();
objParams.anarray.table = $table;
objParams.anarray.cols = $cols;

$.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2',
    objParams,
    function(data) {

    }
);
```

In your controller, the `$_POST['anarray']` will contain the associative array.

So you can access table as `$_POST['anarray']['table']`.

Comment: I don't think the user is using jquery. I might be wrong though.

Comment: lol. I didn't even notice that, my bad. In that case, wouldn't it be easier to just enclose it in a `form` tag and use `serialize()` to grab the data?

Comment: Yup, that works also. I just grabbed that from the project I'm currently working on where I don't use a form.

Comment: And I think he doesn't need all the fields in the form, and just wants to use it in a delete operation. Plus, in the case here, he could just put the data in different variables, not in an array. But, anyway, he asked how to send an array in a post...

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the previous comment, I would've gone a different route. I would enclose the form with a (well) `form` tag and use this code to get the data:

```
function deleteData2() {

    var post_data = $('form').serialize();

    $.post('/json/crewonly/deleteDataAjax2', post_data, function() {

    });
}
```

Then you can access the data via `$_POST` on PHP.

Comment: Yeah I think it would be smart to use serialize, but maybe you can provide a bit more detail on how he could name his form data in a way that would make it easy to process? For example it looks like each checkbox sends three variables for the delete action.